# Show that $(\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z)/(m\mathbb Z\oplus n\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z_n\oplus \mathbb Z_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-isomorphism, ring-isomorphism

show that $(\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z)/(m\mathbb Z\oplus n\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z_n\oplus \mathbb Z_m$
using the first isomorphic theorm
i don't know how actually
but the question ordered the proof of that $(\oplus )/(I\oplus J) ≈ R/I\oplus S/J$  first
and let us base on it to prove the first line

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Maybe apply it with $R=S=\Bbb Z,\ I=m\Bbb Z,\ J=n\Bbb Z$?